# Can we send private messages to friends of a user with offline_access permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Is it possible to send private messages to the friends of a user after getting the offline_access permission from him?

While sending app requests, I know its possible to send app_requests to any user(using app_access_token) who is already a part of the application. Like wise is it possible to send using offline_access permission without using `send` dialog or any other operation which needs the user consent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible, the only Facebook communication channels you can use are stream Posts and App requests, and if the user is offline, you cannot publish posts as it is against [Facebook Platform Policy IV.3](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

If this is user-to-user communication, you may be able to send an email to the users username@facebook.com email address, which will create a message for them. However Policy IV.5 explains the limitations of this.